# Aloha Editor and Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, aloha-editor

I'm having difficulties integrating the Aloha Editor http://www.alohaeditor.org/Content.Node/index.html to Ember.

I'm able to generate an editable area. However, I cannot make the editable text Bold.

I created this JSBin: http://jsbin.com/purosegifa/1/

This line of code `aloha.ui.command(aloha.ui.commands.bold);` is compiled with no error in my app but my text do not become bold. I'm using an example straight out of Aloha getting started guide: http://www.alohaeditor.org/docs/#add-and-bind-a-button. See step 2 to get explanation for the button that bold the text.

I'm thinking that I should implement the step 2 in another way to make it work with Ember. I don't now how however.

Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: You probably want to implement an ember component in order to wrap the aloha functionality within it.

Comment: Please refer to this post for the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218286/bind-directly-to-dom-with-not-event