# Bind directly to DOM with not event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery:

```
$('#big-bad-bold-button')
    .on('click', aloha.ui.command(aloha.ui.commands.bold));
```

It binds the `click` event. How could I achieve the same binding without having to click?

I want to call programatically the function and perform the binding to the DOM without having to click.

***UPDATE***: I created a JSBin with the below solution of StackBox: http://jsbin.com/kofire/3/

Comment: Call `$('#big-bad-bold-button').trigger('click');` which will simulate a user clicking your button.

Comment: I'm new to this forum.  Can someone explain me why I got down voted? Then I could correct the question. tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that **aloha.ui.command** is a higher order function, I think you can

use code like this:

```
aloha.ui.command(aloha.ui.commands.bold)($('#big-bad-bold-button'))
```

Curring is an intereseted thing：http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying